# Shell method on $f(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2 + 1}}$

Tags: calculus

I am trying to find the volume of this from $[0,2]$ about $x = 0$

Since it is about $x$ I know that the shell method uses the opposite variable so I need it in terms of $y$.

$$f(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2 + 1}}$$

$$x = \sqrt{\frac{1}{y} - 1}$$

$$2\pi \int_0^1 y\sqrt{\frac{1}{y} - 1}dy$$

Now I am not certain if this is correct but I am unsure how to get this integral, it seems overly complex. Is there a more simple way to do this?

Comment: Check your limits. Use a common denominator and simplify a bit. Then the integral is straightforward.

Comment: What is it you want to find?

Comment: I have to use the shell method.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, the integral is easy, but it is not the one you wrote.

Comment: How is it easy?

Comment: See Spencer's answer. And note that $x=0$ is the $y$-axis.

Comment: You are trying to find the volume from [0,2], but the bounds of your integral are [0, 1].

Comment: You’re making it too complicated. You’re to revolve the region about the line $x=0$, which is the $y$-axis, not the $x$-axis. To get shells, therefore, you’ll be chopping the region into **vertical** strips, whose width will be $dx$, not $dy$. You should therefore be integrating with respect to $x$, not $y$.

Answer (score 2):

The shell method about x=0 would be

$$V = 2\pi \int_0^2 x f(x) dx$$

In your case this becomes,

$$V = 2\pi \int_0^2 \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}} dx$$

Which is a straight forward u-substitution.

Comment: But it is about the x axis so I need it in turns of y.

Comment: I think you are confused. It is about $x=0$, which is the $y$-axis.

Comment: Not for the shell method. If you were using washers you would need it in terms of y.

Comment: I always forget tht about x = something means it is actually not x.

Comment: @Bob Smith Have you seen there derivations of the formulas? As a student I couldn't keep straight which to use and whether it needed to be in terms of y or x until I saw where the formulas were coming from.

Comment: I have seen the formulas, it just makes it more confusing to memorize it all. There are so many, shell, area under a curve, disk, revolution of a solid. Easier to just memorize that shell uses opposite rest use the same.

Comment: @julien: That is clearly address to OP.

Comment: @Bob Smith I understand the class you're in has a ton of formulas to memorize. I found a video on youtube that may help your understanding of the shell method. Hope this helps: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MYXMC7koJyY

Comment: @user32240 My apologies...

Comment: I am having trouble getting the correct answer, I get $2u^\frac{1}{2}$ evaluated from 1 to 4, why is this wrong?

Comment: Bob, let $u=x^{2}+1$, try to calculate $d(\sqrt{u})$.

Comment: I did do that, and I get $$1/2 \int \frac{1}{\sqrt{u}} du$$

Comment: The result is $2\pi(\sqrt{5}-1)$. You can check if you did right.